# Creating a method with generic param

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, generic-programming

I am trying to create a generic method in a static class like below
to which I will pass paramData at run time.

```
 public static void InsertBulk<T>(string procedure, IDictionary<T,T> paramData)

    {
        //Body
    }
```

This is valid but as soon as i remove `<T>` following method name like below, it start showing
type error. Why is it behaving so.

```
public static void InsertBulk(string procedure, IDictionary<T,T> paramData)
        {

       }

IDictionary<int,string> myparams= new IDictionary<int,string>();
```

As far as my understanding I can call this method using `classname.InsertBulk("MyProc",myparams);`
so, why is it asking for  after method name. What is its use.

Comment: No, you can't use your `myparams`, because the method accepts a `IDictionary<T, T>`, so key and value must be of the same type. `int` and  `string` are of different type... `new Dictionary<string, string>` would be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate things to understand here:

- How you *declare* a generic method
- How you *call* a generic method

You need to include the `<T>` in the method declaration to make it a generic method. Without that, the compiler doesn't know what `T` is... it expects it to be the name of a regular type.

Now when you *call* a generic method, you can specify type arguments like this:

```
InsertBulk<int>("MyProc", myParams);
```

Here there's just one type argument: `int`. (This won't compile for reasons described below, but it's an example of specifying a type argument.)

... or you can let the compiler try to *infer* the type arguments based on the arguments to the method - in this case, it will look at `myParams` and work out what the type argument has to be to make the call compile. The details of type inference are *very* complicated, but they're designed so that where reasonable, you can get away without specifying type arguments.

In your case, as `myParams` is an `IDictionary<int, string>` it can't compile anyway, as there's no `T` for which an `IDictionary<int, string>` is an `IDictionary<T, T>`. You could potentially make your method have *two* type parameters instead:

```
public static void InsertBulk<TKey, TValue>(
    string procedure, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> paramData)
```

That that point you can call `InsertBulk("MyProc", myParams)` and the compiler will infer type arguments of `int` and `string`.

Comment: Whats the solution then if  it cannot be compiled?

Comment: @Sweetie: I'm not sure what you mean. You could make it a generic method with two type parameters, perhaps... but really we have very, very little information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you please give me a example.

Comment: @Sweetie: I've given an example at the bottom of my answer, but please try to be a lot more specific about what you're trying to achieve when you ask a question.